# Distribution of the sum of the number of rolls that result in an even number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'd like to ask for some help in finding the distribution of the number of rolls that result in an even number. The problem goes like this:

> Consider a loaded die where the probability that a roll results in $I$ is $p_i = I/21$, $i = 1,\ldots,6$. Suppose the die is rolled $35$ times and let $N_i$ be the number of times that the roll results in $i$. Then $N = (N_1, \ldots , N_6)$ is multinomial distributed with parameters $35$, $\left(\frac1{21}, \ldots, \frac6{21}\right)$, find the distribution of $X = N_2+N_4+N_6$.

In my attempt, knowing that $N_i$'s follow a $\text{Binomial}(35,p_i)$ distribution, I conditioned on $N_6$, and then on $ N_4$ but my expression was too complicated to simplify. I was wondering if there is an easier way to approach this problem? This is just a practice problem as I study for my exam.

Comment: If you know that $ N_i = Bin (35, p_i)$, then what is $ X$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I see it now: X will follow $Bin(35, p_2+p_4+p_6)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- What is the probability a particular single roll is even?
- Are rolls independent?
- What is the probability exactly $X$ rolls are even out of $35$ total rolls?

Comment: I haven't thought about it in this way! Thank you, it made it al lot easier!